# Null pointer occurs when removing listview item

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter, expandablelistview

I get a null pointer exception when trying to remove an item from my `ListView`.  I believe it is because My ListView is trying to get child views that do not exist, but I do not know how to prevent this because my expandableListView requires child views.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hello.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildrenCount(ExpandableListAdapter.java:89)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:563)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.access$000(ExpandableListConnector.java:50)
            at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector$MyDataSetObserver.onChanged(ExpandableListConnector.java:857)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseExpandableListAdapter.java:56)
            at com.hello.MainActivity.InactiveAlarmSorter3000(MainActivity.java:301)
            at com.hello.MainActivity.doPositiveClick(MainActivity.java:315)
            at com.hello.ArmAlarmFragment$2.onClick(ArmAlarmFragment.java:32)
```

The Logcat states that the error is comming from this method in my expandablelist adapter, but I don't know how to prevent this method from returning null.

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    String test = listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) + "";
    Log.d("Debugd", groupPosition + "");
    Log.d("Debugd", listDataChild + "hi");
    Log.d("Debugd", listDataHeader + "bye");
    Log.d("Debugd", test);

    return this.listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();

}
```

Where Method is being called.

```
   public void StuffSorter3000(String header) {

        Log.d("testingthis", header);

        if (header.equals("SomeStuff")) {
            loadActiveList(header);
        }
        if (header.equals("OtherStuff")) {
            loadActiveList(header);
        }

        ActiveList.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Method that does the adding/removing

```
 public void loadActiveList(String variable) {

        listDataHeaderActive.add(variable);
        listDataHeaderInactive.remove(variable);
    }
```

Adding Variables works well and the items display in my ArrayList, however removing variables from my other ArrayList crashes.

**variable `header` is not null at the beginning of the method.

Comment: The exception occurs in your getChildrenCount() function. Please make sure both listDataChild and listDataHeader are not null. Since these are the only 2 variables you use there, one of them must be the cause.

Comment: It's getChildrenCount() method.  I don't know why this error is happening because Child is not null right before that method.

Comment: When I start making changes from the bottom of the list the exception no longer occurs,  I will look into it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple, but I feel I should leave this question up so nobody else has to waste as much time as I did debugging.

Before removing a parent item I had to make sure that the attached childView was collapsed.
I also invalidated my dataset with `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` instead of using `notifyDataSetChanged()` on my ExpandableListAdapter.  Problem seems to be solved.

```
public void loadActiveList(String variable){

     Inactive.collapseGroup(AlarmPosition);
     listDataHeaderInactive.remove(variable);
     listAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidate();

listDataHeaderActive.add(variable)
ActiveList.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```